# Video.js Playlists in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, video.js

I am attempting to get the React video.js example to work with the videojs-playlist plugin and I keep getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.player.playlist is not a function`. My component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-playlist';

const VideoControl = React.createClass({ 
    componentDidMount() {

      this.player = videojs(this.videoNode);

      this.player.playlist([{
          sources: [{
            src: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
          }],
          poster: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png'
        }, {
          sources: [{
            src: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4'
          }],
          poster: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png'
    }]);
  },

  // destroy player on unmount
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  },


  render() {
    return (

            <div data-vjs-player>
              <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
            </div>

    )
  }
})

export default VideoControl;
```

videojs-playlist does not seem to be adding itself to VideoJS as a plugin. I am on the latest React and Webpack. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that `videojs` initialization is asynchronous? Try adding a setInterval with a console.log of `this.player` and `this.player.playlist` and see it is and we can go from there

Comment: @Grandas Good idea! Unfortunately playlist seems to be continually undefined.

Comment: can you change this line `import 'videojs-playlist'` to `import vPlaylist from 'videojs-playlist'`

Comment: @Muhaimin that does not seem to help. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a Webpack issue. I got it going with the following:

```
import 'expose-loader?videojs!../../../../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.js';
require("script-loader!../../../../node_modules/videojs-playlist/dist/videojs-playlist.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import videojsPlaylistPlugin from 'videojs-playlist';
videojs.registerPlugin('playlist', videojsPlaylistPlugin);
```

works on:

```
"video.js": "~7.0.3",
"videojs-playlist": "~4.2.1"
```